# perform the same operation on many columns in data table, data frame

Tags: r

I need to perform the same operation on each column  for data subseted by the values in another column.
For instance,taking the example below,  for each year and each Var(1,2,3) I need to compute cumsum function and then put the result in another 3 columns (var11, Var22, Var33). 
This outcome I will use it further for different plots.
While doing this in turn for each year I end up with a long piece of code which is realy ugly. 
How can I do it in a more compact and efficient way?

```
dt<-data.table( YEAR = c("2001", "2000", "2001", "2001","1999", "2000", "2000", "1999", "1999"),
                Var1=sample(0:100, 8, rep=TRUE),
                Var2 =sample(0:500, 8, rep=TRUE),
                Var3 =sample(0:500, 8, rep=TRUE)


)
```

Thank you

Comment: How would you do a cumulative sum without another variable ordering the observations within years? What is the logic for ordering?

Comment: The cumsum was just an example of the possible function I would need to do row operations. But to clarify this issue anyway, for each year, each of the Var will be sorted in a descending order and then apply cumsum. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the cols to create, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, paste0(names(dt)[-1], '_cumsum') := lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = YEAR]

#   YEAR Var1 Var2 Var3 Var1_cumsum Var2_cumsum Var3_cumsum
#1: 2001   68  428  314          68         428         314
#2: 2000   47  244  437          47         244         437
#3: 2001   10  312  406          78         740         720
#4: 2001   89  151   58         167         891         778
#5: 1999   62  289  219          62         289         219
#6: 2000   27  317  198          74         561         635
#7: 2000    3  248  371          77         809        1006
#8: 1999   95  328   19         157         617         238
#9: 1999   68  428  314         225        1045         552
```

Comment: thank you very much , it is exactly what i wanted. I have an additional question if possible: the main purpose of my analysis is actually to compute the pareto diagrams for each of the variable (1,2,3) and plot them. is there a simple way of doing this in a shot ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tidy-solution

```
bind_cols(dt, dt%>% mutate_at(vars(matches("Var")), cumsum)%>%
        select(-YEAR)%>%
        rename_at(vars(colnames(dt)[-1]), ~ paste0(colnames(dt)[-1], 1:length(colnames(dt)[-1]))))

   YEAR Var1 Var2 Var3 Var11 Var22 Var33
1: 2001   65  326  460    65   326   460
2: 2000   70   57  371   135   383   831
3: 2001   43   40  465   178   423  1296
4: 2001   57  303   83   235   726  1379
5: 1999   37  234  104   272   960  1483
6: 2000    5  382  462   277  1342  1945
7: 2000   15  136  486   292  1478  2431
8: 1999    1  144  444   293  1622  2875
9: 1999   65  326  460   358  1948  3335
```

Comment: thank you for your replay. There is a little issue: it looks like sorting by year is not working because it computes the cumsum irrespective of the year. Actually, as I mentioned in the other answer, the main purpose of my analysis is actually to compute the pareto diagrams for each of the variable (1,2,3) and plot them. is there a simple way of doing this in a shot ?

Comment: @gogo88 The problem is that your dataframe has three times the same years. You could maybe add `dt<-dt%>%arrange((YEAR))` before my solution.